# How to cut text by length in pixels?

Tags: java, css

I have an algorithmic problem:
There are 4 strings of text which should be placed in one line divided by separator (i.e. |). The width of whole line is known(i.e. 500px). Each string contains words of different length. I want to place first n-words (n depends by length of each word):

1. One
2. Four five
3. Sixty nine
4. One hundred sixteen

I would like to get 4 strings with approximately equals length. And if one of strings is smaller than other must be longer. I.e:

One | Four five... | Sixty nine | One hundred.

The number of initial string can be less. In this case the number of words for each string must be bigger.
I.e:

1. Four five six
2. One hundred sixteen

Will be:

Four five six | One hundred sixteen.

Is it possible to do this with CSS or I should use AffineTransform from Java back-end? I tried to use this approach but it takes a lot of resources and time.

Answer (score 0):

Go through each character and check if it can be added, the widthOf(char) simply returns the width of the character you'll have to set a width for each character and store them.

```
StringBuilder final = "";
int maxWidthPixel = 500;
int currentWidthPixel = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    currentWidthPixel += widthOf(c);
    if(currentWidthPixel <= maxWidthPixel) {
        final.append(c);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

return final.toString();
```

EDIT: This is java code.

Comment: I think he was looking for a css based solution, if I read the question correctly.

Comment: Yeah, he would prefer css, but I don't know css, though if he knows both languages he should be able to convert it to css.

Comment: This comment made my day :)

Comment: Css is not really a programming language in the traditional sense. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets. You can't really convert java to css. Your comment was awesome and apparently made more then just my day! :D

Comment: oh, haha, yeah um sorry @Filosssof had no idea what css was. Not even close, well you're on your own. Have fun!

Comment: I have idea about css. But your code is not the answer for me, because it does not operate with 4 different strings but just one. Also, this approach does not resolve the problem of approximately equals strings. I agree with @zessx  that transforming java code into css is awesome.

Comment: @Sirence Well if he is using web page couldn't he use javascript?

Comment: Yes, I can use JS. But I am interested for the algorithm.

Comment: @Filosssof, I think you will have to resort to using javascript/jquery as I don't think there is a css solution for this.